# Do access token expiration times reset/get updated every time they are used?

Tags: rest-api, session

I have my access token session set to expire every 24 hours, but if someone uses that token (say through a rest API call) at some point, does it last for another 24 hours or does the session not restart?

Comment: @Eric sooooo when i set the session timeout value under session settings, that doesn't affect the access token at all?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

Comment: I read that post eric, but in the answer, it's stated that "Sessions expire based on your organization's policy for sessions. Basically, as long as the app is in active use, the session won't expire." Is he not referring to the access token here? Because the originally question in that thread was asking about the access token..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Access Tokens", as well as "SOAP Session Identifiers" ("sid" for short, in most cases) are all treated the same. They are sessions that have an expiration date. You can see your sessions in Setup > Security Controls > Session Management.

Any use of a session at least 50% of the way through the expiry time, such as running a query, updating a record, or even getting the server time stamp will result in the session being updated. This behavior is the same for all types of sessions, no matter where they originated from.

In other words, a 24-hour expiry means that the user must do *something* with the token at least once in the last 12 hours. Any time the user does something, the timer is reset.

You can verify this behavior by checking out the Session Management screen.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted to know. Now one other thing i was wondering is, what if I reuqest a new access token (using the user-agent flow), does that count as "doing something with the token" or is the time not reset?

Comment: Does this answer mean you don't see the question as a dupe?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I can see how one *could* consider it a dupe, because this answer is partially contained in the answer in the other question, but the other question was about "how to know when the session expires" versus "does the session expire while you're using it"... Which makes the two strongly related, but not identical, in my opinion.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought it was reasonable to decide either way, then saw you answered here as well and became less sure. It doesn't much matter if we have a few near duplicates on here anyway, and in this case it seems distinct enough.

Comment: @NicholasSiegmundt Using a login flow creates a new token, so any existing tokens won't be updated. Keep in mind that there's also a 5-per-client-id limit, so if there's more than five, the oldest ones will be killed.

Comment: @sfdcfox Sorry I meant user-password flow not user-agent flow. And each time I request an access token, it gives me the same one if it hasn't expired yet. So does that mean if I keep requesting it, the expiration time will keep resetting correct?